# Media Queries not working properly in landscape

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

When viewing the website in portrait mode on my Nexus 5, it looks the way I want. However, when I turn the phone over to landscape mode, it shows the full site and not what is specified within this media query.

Why is this happening? I've also tried:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
```

This did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Make working fiddle and let us know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Nexus 5 Landscape width is **590px** and you have given the **max-width:480px**....

[See the view-port sizes](http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=nexus)

You can give the media queries like this also :-

```
@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) {
.class-name {}
}

@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) and (orientation :landscape) {
.class-name {}
}
```

it should work for you... try with this

Answer (score 0):

The nexus 5's effective screen dimensions are 360x598 so in landscape the viewport is wider than the highest end of your media query. You can capture the landscape orientation of the nexus 5 by increasing your max-width to 599px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) { ... }
```

[reference](http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=nexus)